# What's the base URL for my app?

Tags: ruby, rack, camping

In Camping/Rack, how can I get the base URL for my app? I want to know so I can put it in an email it sends.

It might be (in development)

or

```
http://localhost:9292
```

or

```
http://localhost:80/game
```

or in production

```
http://fancy-snake.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camping has a helper called [`URL`](https://camping.github.io/camping.io/api/#M000004) which returns the absolute URL to your app:

```
URL()               # => #<URL:http://test.ing/blog/>
URL() + "view/12"   # => #<URL:http://test.ing/blog/view/12>
URL("/view/12")     # => #<URL:http://test.ing/blog/view/12>
```

Answer (score 2):

So far I have

```
url = @env['rack.url_scheme'] + "://" + @env['HTTP_HOST'] + R(LoginX, u.secret)
```

Which seems to work for the first and third cases. I don't know if it's write if the app is at `localhost/prefix`

Answer (score 2):

You have to be a little careful with this, as there are a some subtle potential traps. The [`Rack::Request` class](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/request.rb) will probably be helpful here.

First, you can’t really get the url for the *app*, as it may be responding to multiple urls (via Rack routes, Apache config, etc), so you’re looking at getting the url for the particular *request*. If you’re only serving requests from one url this won’t matter.

The scheme for the request is in the `env` hash under the `rack.url_scheme`, but this is only for the “last leg” of the request. If your app is behind a proxy of some sort (Nqinx, Apache etc.) then you want to get the scheme of the real request, not the request from the proxy to the machine your app is running on. If you’ve configured your proxy correctly it should be setting a header so you can tell what the original scheme was. [`Rack::Request` has a `scheme` method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/request.rb) that takes these headers into account.

The host for the url is *probably* in the `env` hash under the `HTTP_HOST` key, but this header is not necessarily present (admittedly that’s pretty unlikey nowadays). You should fall back on `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT`. Additionally there’s the issue of handling proxied requests, you want the hostname of the original request, not the backend server. Again, `Rack::Request` provides [`host_with_port`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/request.rb#L88-94) and [`host`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/request.rb#L110-113) methods that deal with these issues.

`Rack::Request` also provides a [`base_url` method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/request.rb#L110-113) that combines scheme and host, and additionally only includes the port if differs from the default (80 or 443).

The location that your app is mounted is in the `env` hash under the `SCRIPT_NAME` key. This would be `/game` in your second example, and can be empty if your app mounted at the root of your server. Again, `Rack::Request` provides a [`script_name` method](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/request.rb#L25), although this one simply returns the value of the entry in the `env` hash.

So, in summary, you probably want to use something like this:

```
req = Rack::Request.new env
url = req.base_url + req.script_name
```

which looks pretty simple, but is taking care of various possibilities for you.

Additionally, you miight find the the [Rack specification](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html) useful to have a read of, it contains details of the various entries that should be in the `env` hash.