# Configuring Rack::Static

Tags: ruby, file, rack

I'm building a Rack application which serves static and dynamic resources, and I'm trying to use `Rack::Static` middleware to do this.

The idea is serving all requests for static files and pass the requests that won't match this catogory, the dynamic requests, to my application. But I junt don't know how to do this and the documentation for `Rack::Static` is not very clear about how to do this.

This is my basic configuration file by now:

#### config.ru

```
#\ -w -p 8888

require_relative 'be/emeraldfw/emerald_app'

# use Rack::Reloader, 0
# use Rack::ContentLength
use Rack::Static, :urls => [""], :root => 'public', :index => 'pages/index.html'

run EmeraldApp.new
```

which just serves requests for `/` with `public/pages/index.html`, since the declared root is `public`.

This is far from being enough.

I need to serve all standard image files from `public/resources/images`, all CSS files from `public/resources/css` and so on.

Could someone give a hint about how to do this? I've been fighting this problem for two days now.

Comment: does it work if you remove `index`?

Comment: It works if I mention my files like `<img src='resources/images/some_image.jpg' />`, for example. But I don't want this. I need to write only `<img src='some_image.jpg' />` and have it served from the correct directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the base URL for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885012/whats-the-base-url-for-my-app)